# How to pre-load images used only on hover?

Tags: css, images, load-time

I have a link that starts with one background image and then changes on hover to another.  Both background images are set in the CSS.  My browsers (any of them) don't seem to load the hover image until you actually hover.  But then you end up with a blank image for the several seconds (on my very slow connection) it takes to load the new one.  Is there a way to encourage the browser to pre-load the hover image so that delay time doesn't occur on hover?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1) Use [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) (This is the preferred method).

2) Load the images in a hidden div. Place the images in the div and then set the div's CSS to `display: none;` to hide it.

3) [Load the images with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819336/how-to-preload-images-without-javascript):

```
#preloadedImages
{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    display: inline;
    background-image: url(path/to/image1.png);
    background-image: url(path/to/image2.png);
    background-image: url(path/to/image3.png);
    background-image: url(path/to/image4.png);
    background-image: url();

}
```

4) Use [this JavaScript](http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5214317.html)

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function preloader() 
{
     // counter
     var i = 0;

     // create object
     imageObj = new Image();

     // set image list
     images = new Array();
     images[0]="image1.jpg"
     images[1]="image2.jpg"
     images[2]="image3.jpg"
     images[3]="image4.jpg"

     // start preloading
     for(i=0; i<=3; i++) 
     {
          imageObj.src=images[i];
     }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to load them after the page is loaded? So the user doesn't see a loading circle on the cursor? One way would be having a hidden frame that uses javascript to delay the hidden frame to be displayed, such in my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437091/is-it-possible-to-not-load-an-iframe-in-a-hidden-div-until-the-div-is-displayed but is there a preferred method for delaying and not displaying the loading circle on that cursor?

Comment: Nevermind, I found this http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/ and it works flawlessly with time delay.

Answer (score 10):

I don't really like the javascript solution - it's messy, difficult to maintain, and of course completely fails when JS is disabled.

The modern solution is to use [CSS Sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) - try it, believe me, you'll wonder why you never did this before ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found this link on how to pre-load images using pure CSS:

http://www.thecssninja.com/css/even-better-image-preloading-with-css2

And it worked for me when I need to change the different background images on hover.

Comment: It works nicely with Safari and Chrome, but still does not work in 2020 for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Add this above your CSS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg'];

for(var i = 0, len = images.length; i < len; i++) {
  new Image().src = images[i];
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_css_file.css" />
```

If you go the sprite route as danp suggests you still have an issue with loading the sprite before it's needed. That said I love sprites; to easily make them I use the [spriteme tool](https://github.com/stevesouders/spriteme) from Steve Souders: